# Using a spinner to open up a new activity and displaying downloaded html data

Tags: android, methods, spinner, http-get

```
String[] songList = {
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",

 };
Spinner sp;


        TextView selection;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            selection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selection);

            Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

            ArrayAdapter<Object> aa = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    songList);

            aa.setDropDownViewResource(
               android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spin.setAdapter(aa);
        }

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            selection.setText(songList[position]);
            String song = songList[position];
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Tabview.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("song", song);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            selection.setText("");
        }
{
```

I have this code written right now. Pretty much what I'm trying to do is use the spinner selection to open a new activity (which I have done) BUT, I am also trying to use httpget to  download information based on a link.

So, for ex:
If I press "1", it will open up a new activity, then it will call an httpget method, then it will download the data based on what you pressed. and that data will change for each option you press (EX. "1"= google.com, "2"=facebook.com, etc.) and then that data will be displayed in the activity.

I also want to only use ONE activity to display the data for each selection.

Also in my "Tabview.class" I have:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
    String song = b.getString("song");
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly is the error you get? The code seems to work. If you wanted to choose something according to the selection, you can use a simple if condition on the bundled string. Or if the issue here is about http get, take a look at the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html). You can use an AyncTask to make an http request without blocking.

For a reference, I have attached my code which just an improved version of your code.

```
public class ActivityxActivity extends Activity {
    String[] songList = {"ONE","TWO","THREE"};
    Intent intent1;
    Bundle strs;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<Object> aa = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, songList);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp.setAdapter(aa);
        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
        intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AnotherActivity.class);
    }
    public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)  {
            strs = new Bundle();
            strs.putInt("item", pos);
            strs.putString("song", parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
            intent1.putExtras(strs);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
    }
}
```

And in the other activity,

```
public class AnotherActivity extends Activity {
    Bundle data;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        data = getIntent().getExtras();
        Integer item = data.getInt("item");
        //Use a switch(item) here to switch to different links based on selection
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv.setText("Another Activity, Item is :" + item.toString());
    }
}
```

Make sure you add your activity in the Android Manifest file.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for this! But If I have about a hundred different words in my String[]{}; is there a way to link each of them to a certain web address without having to do a hundred different if statements?

Comment: ok, If the above solution worked, please accept the answer. You can use a custom adapter which can adapt a custom ArrayList which associates each item with its corresponding web address. But I suggest you to ask the question in a different thread. Thanks.